# Archaeology: what *was* object type 004?

Tags: sobject, standard-objects, deprecation

So we've all eyeballed the various standard object Key Prefixes at some point and noted:

`001` is `Account`

`003` is `Contact`

etc

I've *always* wondered: what *was* `004`? What about `002`?

Comment: `004` is AWOL too. I could have a gander "`Product1`" and "`Pricebook1`" :P

Comment: http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html @DanielBallinger

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/why-am-i-getting-insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-error-on-code-tha is an unsolved mystery about `004` :)

Comment: you are the fountain of wisdom @eyescream

Comment: Fountain goes to bed, it's 01:24 AM over here (pretty number btw) ;)

Comment: @eyescream I wrote a page that enumerates all currently recognized prefixes (does not work for poly prefixes, as listed on fish of prey). Found some other interesting ones...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

002 is a Note, 004 has apparently not been used.

Source:

```
System.debug(Id.valueOf('002000000000000').getSObjectType()); // Note
System.debug(Id.valueOf('004000000000000').getSObjectType()); // Cannot locate Apex Type for ...
```